# 1 Cannot find symbol : when compiling java code

Tags: java

I have written this program. When I compiled it, it gives error `Symbol not find` 
Plz help me.

```
// File Test.java

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.io.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]){

  Student s1 = newStudent("ali",15);
  student S2 = newStudent();

  s1.print();
  s2.print();

  s2.setName("usman");
  s2.setRollNo(20);

  System.out.println("Student name:"+ s2.getName());
  System.out.println("rollNo:" + s2.getRollNo());

  System.out.println("calling copy constructor");
  Student s3 = newStudent(s2);

   s2.print();
   s3.print();

   s3.setRollNo(-10);

   s3.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: could you give us the complete stacktrace ?

Comment: Do you have spaces between 'new' and 'Student'; in the first two lines of the method?

Comment: Please always give the exact error message. Is `student` the symbol which is not found? Probably you meant `Student` (with a capital).

Comment: @vincent: It's a compile-time error. There won't be a stack trace, unless the OP is using an IDE which allows them to run code which hasn't compiled correctly, which is a bad idea...

Comment: lots of problems, candidates for `Symbol not found` are: `newStudent`, `s2` (uc/lc mismatch), and `Student` itself (no import) — if it's not in the same package.

Comment: Please first check all your capitals and spaces e.g. line 4 should read : Student s2 = new Student() - and BTW, a student without a name and/or rollNo (whatever that is) should not be allowed....

Comment: I think student S2 = newStudent(); should be Student S2 = newStudent();

Comment: I suspect `student s2` should be `Student s2` as the case you use matters.

Answer (score 2):

Salaam,

You need to replace newStudent() with new student(),so your code looks like:

Before:

```
Student s1 = newStudent("ali",15);
Student S2 = newStudent();
```

After:

```
Student s1 = new Student("ali",15);
Student S2 = new Student();
```

Good luck.

Comment: You also needs to replace the S2 declaration from `student S2` to `Student S2` using a Capital letter. Class names are case sensitive.